# Duvida sobre Lista Python

Tags: python

Tenho estas listas:

```py
data_list_com_todos_os_dados = [x for x in queryset_data if x not in data_list_all]

data_list_ que conta_repetições = { y:data_list_3.count(y) for y in set(data_list_3)}
```

que me retorna esse resultado:

```
{'2019-06-08': 2, '2019-06-06': 2, '2019-06-10': 2, '2019-06-03': 1, '2019-06-02': 2, '2019-06-04': 1}
```

é o resultado que eu esperava.

estou usando python3 e django2 pra criar gráficos, mas estou com dificuldade de pegar só o valor dos itens para coloca-los no em outra ou mesma lista mantendo as posições, pois assim o JSON poso renderizar os dados e gerar o gráfico.

eu acho que a lista que criei tem 3 posições: `[index,valor:quantidade_de_vezes_que_se_repete]` e não estou conseguindo pegar só a `quantidade_de_vezes_que_se_repete`. Li e pesquisei um bocado mas não consegui sanar minha duvida.

Answer (score 2):

O que você criou não é uma lista, é um dicionário. Um dicionário é um mapa que relaciona o par chave/valor. No seu caso as datas são as chaves e a quantidade de vezes que se repete são os valores.

Como você quer apenas uma lista de valores, basta fazer `data_list.values()`. Isso retornará um [*view object*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), que é um objeto iterável. Se realmente precisar de uma lista poderá fazer:

```
data_values = list(data_list.values())
```

> **Nota:** recomendo mudar o nome `data_list` uma vez que a estrutura não é uma lista. Não faz diferença na execução do código, mas deixa mais legível.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, vou dar mais uma lida sobre dicionario e lista pois me compliquei com isso eu jurando que estava montando listas e não dics muito obrigado mesmo. e vou mudas para dics todas pois legibilidade é muito importante no código, um avez que sta ficando gigante o código.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu acho que vale comentar também: a menos que você tenha **absoluta certeza** que você não terá mais de um dado na mesma data, evite usá-las como chaves, pois estas são únicas. Ou seja, se você usar datas como chaves num dicionário e tiver mais de um dado em alguma data, você vai acabar perdendo este dado.

Comment: @MuriloSitonio Bem observado, mas neste caso parece não correr esse risco visto que o valor armazenado é justamente a quantidade de vezes que a data se repetiu na estrutura original.